# Connecting refused while connecting to kubernetes using Kubernetes Continuous Deploy plugin

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm using [Kubernetes Continuous Deploy Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes-cd/) to deploy and I'm using pipeline and this is stage to deploy into kubernetes in the Jenkinsfile:

```
   stage('Deploy to k8s'){
    steps{
    kubernetesDeploy(
     configs:'quarkusAgrata.yaml',
     kubeconfigId:'KUBERNETES_CLUSTER_CONFIG',
     enableConfigSubstitution:true
    )
   }
   }
```

I am getting these errors even after correctly configuring

[image]

My KUBERNETES_CLUSTER_CONFIG image

[image]

Comment: Connection parameters in configuration file might be wrong. Please provide the content of file configured against KUBERNETES_CLUSTER_CONFIG here.

Comment: I had updated question with KUBERNETES_CLUSTER_CONFIG image @vsbehere

Comment: @dattaambareesh I have faced the same issue. I have minikube running locally. Did you manage to find a solution? I have entered the kube config data directly

Answer (score 0):

Log on to the box/container/pod hosting Jenkins and try to ping the IP, if alls good, try to telnet to the IP AND port. Depending on the results you should know whether or not a connection is possible from your Jenkins host. Note: if you have Jenkins running in a Container On a pod, you may need to ssh into the container on the pod. Make sure you're in the correct environment when trying to debug. Otherwise you'll kid yourself into thinking you're forming a connection from the Jenkins host when you might not be at quite the right level.

`ping 123.123.123.123` - show whether a connection to the host is possible on the ping port.
`telnet 123.123.123.123 8080` - connecting to a specific port via telnet - if all is good the connection should be opened. If you don't have the telnet application on the pod you may need to install it.. or else you can spin up a busybox container which has various tools alongside telnet for debugging.

Comment: In SSH Credentials section I had added the credentials with option SSH username with private key. In that I had configured private key as a key which is there in kube.config file.Is that the right way?